# C variant with last value implicit return

Tags: c, return, return-value

In LISP, Ruby, Tcl, and several other dynamic languages, the procedure/method/function returns by default, the last value. I.e., there is no need to explicitly use the return command in the last evaluated statement.
Is there a C variant with the same functionality?

Comment: @Samidamaru this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: Techincally, if you have a function with a return type, but lack a `return` statement, there _might_ be a chance that you'll return the last value you touched in your function body: _"Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no expression. In either case, the return value is undefined."_ This is UB, however, so you could also accidentally kill all the ponies and send out your banking details to your neighbours... anything could happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return the value of the the last expression evaluated then either:

1. you have to use `return` statement or
2. use a `pointer` variable to make available the last value in calling function or
3. Save that value in external file and then reading that value from that file in calling function.

There is no other way to access the "last value" in called function in C.

Answer (score 4):

There are no C "variants"; there is C, and there are other languages. And C doesn't do as you wish.

For what it's worth, I don't think that style of programming is very clear at all.
I propose you re-evaluate whether you *really* want to use it.

Comment: It was a styling option, rather than something major. I personally prefer using return, as it makes the code more readable. In LISP it is an issue... I use return in Tcl and Ruby, when programming, even when the functionality stays the same w/o using it. It makes the code more readable. This was to test the applicability of fast code style checkers.